# Is shortcut to select everything which is to the rightside of the cursor in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

The current shortcut which i use to do this is **ctrl + shift + ->** but this shortcut selects the words one by one. isn't there an alternative which does this in one go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just click SHIFT + END, to get ALL to RIGHT or SHIFT + HOME to get ALL to LEFT :)